Solving non-homogeneous equation using DSolve
I am trying to find the equation for temperature distribution on a 2D circular geometry. The heat equation involves a heat source term, and is thus, a non-homogeneous equation. The solution to the homegeneous part of temperature equation (Laplace equation) is:
T[r_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (C1*r + C2/r^2)*Cos[\[Theta]]

and the equation I am trying to solve is:
eqn = Laplacian[g[r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]},"Spherical"] == f[r]/ki*Cos[\[Theta]]

where
f[r_] := Q0*r^n

I tried to solve this equation as per the example from the mathematica documentation:
DSolve[{eqn /. {g -> (T2[#1] &)}}, T2[r], r]

The resulting temperature distribution equation I get is:
{{T2[r] -> -(C[1]/r) + C[2] + (Q0 r^(2 + n) Cos[\[Theta]])/(ki (2 + n) (3 + n))}}

I see that the resulting solution does not have the homogeneous solution.
Can someone please explain to me why this is happening, and how can I fix this to get the correct solution?
Thanks in advance!

Thank you for your comment, but I am still confused, because i want the solution to be in terms of (c1*r + c2/r^2)*cos(theta) terms. I understand that there is homogeneous solution, but it is not the same, Hence I am a little confused, can you please help me to understand this part here?


I see that the resulting solution does not have the homogeneous
solution.

Hard to reply in comment since need to make pic using my advanced skill with paint.exe
Solution is correct
T[r_, θ_, ϕ_] := (a*r + b/r^2)*Cos[θ]
f[r_]:=Q0*r^n
eqn = Laplacian[g[r, θ, ϕ], {r, θ, ϕ},    "Spherical"] == f[r]/ki*Cos[θ]
ode = eqn /. {g -> (T2[#1] &)}


sol = DSolve[ode, T2, r]


ode/.sol //FullSimplify
{True}


You have a homogeneous solution and an inhomogeneous solution.  You simply need to add them together, come up with some initial conditions for the initial temperature at r=0 or r=1 (or some other location) and then pin down the exact functional dependence of f on r (it's raised to the nth power, but in practice, this is a constant in the superscript of r).
See other heat equation solutions:
Stack Exchange Heat Equation PDE Full explanation
